# AngularJS one way binding using ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I isolate ngModel in a directive without a two-way binding. My current code is not working:

```
scope: {
  ngModel: "&"
},
```

I don't get my collection but a method instead.

Comment: I think u mean @. scope : { test : '@'}. <directive test="{{variable}}">. But this wont work with ngModel directive.

Comment: there's actually an example of how to work with ngModel. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example

Answer (score 0):

depending on your angular version, you could use in your view `::` to turn two-way data-binding in to one way.

for example:

```
<element ng-model="::object.value"></element>
```

this should work from angular version 1.3 and up

Comment: this is not one way binding

Comment: That's a one-time binding, so it won't refresh after the initial binding.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia " An expression that starts with `::` is considered a __one-time__ expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below)."

Comment: in the One-time binding section

Answer (score 0):

ngModel uses a two-way binding. So you need to eval that as an expression, and then use the result.

```
<element ng-model="myvar"></element>

$scope.$watch(function() {
     return attr.ngModel
}, function(value) {
     var oneWay = $scope.$eval(value);
});
```

Don't use an isolated scope, because you want access to the scope that is on the element that ngModel is on.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do what you asking. (Having no idea if this can be used for something useful thow)
If you declare isolated scope and use ng-model, you can get value from ngModelCtrl.(require it in directive):

```
app.directive('test', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope : {},
    require: 'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log(ctrl);
      ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
        scope.test = ctrl.$modelValue;
        console.log('test = ', scope.test)
      })
    }
  };
});
```

And you have ngModel value in your isolated scope one-way binded.
http://plnkr.co/edit/4xGhb5OYRVg6gtzLDHlY?p=preview